# JQuery Changing Content on Scroll Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How would you go about achieving the same effect as is shown on [this site](http://fresh01.co.za/)? When a specific post comes into the focus of the two blue circular things, data about that post is shown in both circle things. Are there any jQuery plugins made especially for this?

I know that they are using an overlay, I am wondering more about the switching of the content when a specific post is in the focus of the blue circles.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. They have a blue background that is sync with the content. on top of that they added an overlay layer to cover that. It makes you feel the circles changes their content while scrolling. check [this](http://fresh01.co.za/wp-content/themes/fresh03/images/header.png) overlay image, you will get what's going there! :)

Comment: Actually, the content in the blue circles is being swapped out with JavaScript. You can tell if you scroll back and forth between 2 posts.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted - this IS how you do it, although you need JS to change the date and pic - its a nice trick.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how that part of the trick works, I am asking for help regarding the switching of content as different divs come into the focus of the blue circles.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the site using Firebug you will see that this is actually just a show/hide of spans when the a particular post is in view. Some simple calculation to determine the position of the element wrapping each post on the screen.

Something to the effect of :

```
<div class="post-wrapper">
    <span class="date"></span>
    <div class="post"></div>
    <span class="type"></span>
</div>
```

Calculate the position of `post-wrapper`

If it is at some position hide the `<span>`s in the previous `post-wrapper` and show the `<span>`s of the current `post-wrapper`

Along with some nifty CSS positioning of course.

Comment: How do I go about calculating the current position of `post-wrapper`?